# Objective-C library category methods not working in Swift app environment

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, categories, xcode6.3

I have an Objective-C iOS app that is composed of a workspace (AuthPort.xcworkspace) with a project (AuthPort.xcodeproj) and an Objective-C SDK project ("ANet SDK.xcodeproj") which builds a library called “libAnet SDK.a”).

“libAnet SDK.a” is linked in with the AuthPort target Build Phases.

In the SDK, there are some categories on NSString which get built into “libAnet SDK.a”.  They are named:

NSString+stringWithXMLTag.h and NSString+stringWithXMLTag.m
.
.
.
etc.

Some code in the AuthPort.xcodeproj calls code in the library which in turn calls these category methods.

It all works smoothly in the above Objective-C environment!

Now…I am re-writing the AuthPort code in Swift in a new workspace with a new project and also using the Objective-C SDK which builds “libAnet SDK.a”

So, I created a new Swift Xcode project called AuthPort.xcodeproj and added it to a new workspace called AuthPort.xcworkspace.  I also added the authorize.net SDK ("ANet SDK.xcodeproj", written in Objective-C) to the project.

So far, so good.  I created an AuthPort-Bridging-Header.h file and imported all the headers from the SDK (without the category headers - more on this later).  I also linked in “libAnet SDK.a” in the Build Phases of the AuthPort target.

AuthPort builds and runs with no errors or warnings.

Now, in viewDidLoad of the primary view controller I added code to access library methods to register a new device with the company, authorize.net:

```
var r: MobileDeviceRegistrationRequest = MobileDeviceRegistrationRequest()

an.mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest(r)
```

These two calls are the same library methods in both Objective-C and Swift versions.  The last method calls other library methods which call methods from the NSString category above.

When I put breakpoints in a category method in the Objective-C environment (all Objective-C code in app and library), the program breaks as expected and I can step through the code.

When I put breakpoints in a category method in the Swift environment (Swift app project with Objective-C library), the debugger never enters a category method.  At one point in the execution, the app SIGABRT’s with the following:

```
2015-04-21 12:25:47.388 AuthPort[4743:2404231] +[NSString stringWithXMLTag:andValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x38450e18
```

2015-04-21 12:25:47.390 AuthPort[4743:2404231] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSString stringWithXMLTag:andValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x38450e18'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x29a0a5a7 0x3792fc77 0x29a0f989 0x29a0d949 0x2993eb68 0xd9e4b 0xc301f 0xdd507 0xc4725 0xc44b1 0xb8f28 0xb9e60 0x2cf0eb65 0x2cf0e8d5 0x2d031c43 0x2d031ac7 0x2d03196b 0x2cf1b5f1 0x2d0357b3 0x2d03491f 0x2cf2433b 0x2cf159e1 0x2cf15003 0x2cf14e6b 0x2cf148ef 0x2cf121ef 0x2cf7c031 0x2d16e34f 0x2d170781 0x2d17b1a9 0x2d16f063 0x302880a1 0x299d125d 0x299d0521 0x299cecbf 0x2991bb51 0x2991b963 0x2cf72b8f 0x2cf6dc91 0xb5290 0x37ed8aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

The [NSString stringWithXMLTag:andValue:] is from the category added by the library onto NSString.

The library method stringOfXMLRequest calls the category method stringWithXMLTag:andValue:

```
- (NSString *) stringOfXMLRequest {

NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""
               @"<merchantAuthentication>"
               @"%@"        //name (optional)
               @"%@"        //fingerPrint type Object                                      @"%@"        //transactionKey or
               @"%@"        //sessionToken or
               @"%@"        //password
               @"%@"        //mobileDeviceId (optional)
               @"</merchantAuthentication>",
               (self.name ? [NSString stringWithXMLTag:@"name" andValue:self.name] : @""),
               (self.fingerPrint ? [self.fingerPrint stringOfXMLRequest] : @""),
               (self.transactionKey ? [NSString stringWithXMLTag:@"transactionKey" andValue:self.transactionKey] : @""),
               (self.sessionToken ? [NSString stringWithXMLTag:@"sessionToken" andValue:self.sessionToken] : @""),
               (self.password ? [NSString stringWithXMLTag:@"password" andValue:self.password] : @""),
               (self.mobileDeviceId ? [NSString stringWithXMLTag:@"mobileDeviceId" andValue:self.mobileDeviceId] : @"")];

return s;
```

}

The SIGABRT doesn't happen until the second call is made to stringWithXMLTag:andValue: for the transitionKey.

The exact same library code is run in both environments.

Here’s the code from stringWithXMLTag:andValue: which is never seen in the debugger:

```
+ (NSString *)stringWithXMLTag:(NSString *)t andValue:(NSString *)v {
if (v == nil) {
    return @"";
}
else { 
    v = [NSString stringWithEscapedXMLValue:v];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>%@</%@>", t, v, t];
}
```

}

The problem is solely within the library code where a library method calls another library method which calls a library category method which is never entered in the debugger in the Swift version.

I also tried adding the category header files in the bridging header and adding -ObjC and -all_load to the Other Linker Flags for AuthPort.  No luck.

I’ve searched the net for 2 days with no luck.  Hopefully one of you will have seen this behavior.

I'm building using Xcode 6.3 and iOS 8.3 (deploying on iOS 8.2).

Thanks.

Comment: Is libAnet SDK.a a Framework or a static library? In my Swift project using a Objective-C Framework I cannot set breakpoint either, so this should be a good radar...

Comment: It's an SDK source code library project that's built as a dependency of the AuthPort project, so I guess it's a Framework.  That's interesting that you can't step into breakpoints in category method code either.  Perhaps my crash comes from an unrelated problem.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Have you tried my answer? Specially the "mark as public" all category headers part

Comment: Yes, see the comment to your answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Check that:

1. you've added you category to the Umbrella Framework of your Framework project. Use `#import "your.h"`
2. I've marked the .h file from the category as public. Select the .h > Identity and Type > Target Membership > Public
3. In your project, set correct Framework Search Paths

Comment: In the all-Objective-C version, one can select a Target Membership for a header file.  In the Swift version I can't do this so there's no way to set to public.  Could this have changed in iOS 8 since my Swift is deployed to iOS 8.2 and my ObjC version deployed to iOS 5.1 and above?  Search paths are set and #imports added.

Comment: I mean in the Objective-C part (the Framework). There, select your .h file, Open `Identity and type` panel and you'll see your .h are set to `project`. Change them to `public`

Comment: The checkboxes for Anet SDK and Anet SDKTest are greyed out in Target Membership and cannot be checked to reveal the public and private choices.  Only in the all-Objective-C project do I get the choice to make public.

Comment: I also tried adding a "Headers" build phase and putting the category headers in it's public section.  This had no affect either.